# Exclude label tags that have input type="radio" child nodes using Xpath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, contains

When parsing the source code of https://www.gov.uk/contact/govuk I want to be able to filter out the label tags that have input type="radio" as child nodes using Xpath.

I've been trying a variety of solutions like the following:

```
$labels = $xpath->query('//label[not(contains(@type, "radio"))]');
$labels = $xpath->query('//label[not(contains(input[@type], "radio"))]');
```

Neither of which seems to produce the desired result, which is a set of all label tags, besides those that have  child nodes.

Is this possible with Xpath, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath for `<label>` that doesn't have child `<input>` having `type` *contains* text `"radio"` :

```
//label[not(input[contains(@type, "radio")])]
```

or `<label>` that doesn't have child `<input>` having `type` equals `"radio"` :

```
//label[not(input[@type="radio"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work :

```
//label[not(input/@type='radio')]
```

or

```
//label[input/@type!='radio']
```